# Help with `alignat` with 3 columns where some lines don't need alignment at third column

Tags: align, alignment, alignat

The title is potentially confusing and worded poorly. If anyone would like to correct it, by all means, please do. Here is what I currently have:

[image]

**Code**:

```
    \item \textbf{Example}. Apply this for $n = 1$ and obtain
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        &&f(x) &= f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + \int_a^x (x - a)f''(t) \,dt \\
        \iff&& f'(a) &= \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} - \underbrace{\frac{1}{x - a} \int_a^x (x - t)f''(t) \,dx}_{\text{``error"}} \\
        \iff&& \left|f'(a) - \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}\right| &\leq \frac{1}{x - a}\int_a^x |(x - t)| \cdot |f''(t)| \,dt \leq \sup_{[a, b]}\left|f''(t)\right| \frac{1}{2(x - a)}(x - a)^2
    \end{alignat*}
```

**Problem**:
I would like to add a *fourth* line which is a simplification of the `\sup_{[a, b]}\left|f''(t)\right| \frac{1}{2(x - a)}(x - a)^2` on the third line. That is, it should be aligned with the `\leq` before the `\sup ...` section on the third line. However, I do not "need" this alignment on the first two lines, if that is clear.
I have tried reading the official documentation from AMS and looking at other examples, but the problem is that I don't need to align the equation on the first two lines, so it is slightly confusing.

Comment: You could align on the second column, and repeat the part between there and the `\leq` within a `\phantom`, in effect skipping over it.  That way you wouldn't need to establish another alignment point.

Comment: Thank you, using the phantom command worked.

Comment: OT, but are you sure you want to write it like that with the `\iff`s? Do you really have equivalent statements? I would suggest [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMOs4.png) (can surely be improved if one knows the context).

Comment: @mickep Yes you are right. I type these notes on the fly in my analysis class so sometimes I don't think of reformatting afterward. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possibilities:

- Use an interior `aligned` environment.
- Use an `alignat*{3}` environment, and use `\mathrlap` directives (provided by the `mathtools` package, a superset of the `amsmath` package) to "hide" the material to the right of the second alignment points in rows 1 and 2.

Both possibilities are illustrated in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter, \mathclap, and \mathrlap macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert % abs. val.
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman text and math fonts)

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Example}. Apply this for $n=1$ and obtain
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &&f(x)   
    &= f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \int_a^x (x-a)f''(t) \,dt \\[\jot]
\iff&& f'(a) &= \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} - 
       \underbrace{\frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x (x-t)f''(t) \,dx}_{\text{``error''}} \\
\iff&& \abs*{f'(a) - \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}} 
    &\leq \frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x \abs{(x-t)} \cdot \abs{f''(t)} \,dt 
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      &\leq \sup_{\mathclap{[a, b]}}\, \abs{f''(t)} \frac{1}{2(x-a)}(x-a)^2\\
      &=    \tfrac{1}{2} \sup_{\mathclap{[a, b]}}\, \abs{f''(t)}(x-a)\,.
    \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\item \textbf{Example}. Apply this for $n=1$ and obtain
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    &&f(x)   
    &= \mathrlap{f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \int_a^x (x-a)f''(t) \,dt} \\[\jot]
\iff&& f'(a) &= \mathrlap{\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} - 
       \underbrace{\frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x (x-t)f''(t) \,dx}_{\text{``error''}}} \\
\iff&& \abs*{f'(a) - \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}} 
    &\leq \frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x \abs{(x-t)} \cdot \abs{f''(t)} \,dt 
    &&\leq \sup_{\mathclap{[a, b]}}\,\abs{f''(t)} \frac{1}{2(x-a)}(x-a)^2\\
    &&&&&= \tfrac{1}{2}\sup_{\mathclap{[a, b]}}\,\abs{f''(t)}(x-a)\,.
\end{alignat*}
    
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```